# mysql - usage of memory still grow up

Tags: mysql, memory

I have problem with my production mysql server. Usage of memory still grow up and I don`t know why. Trouble started when we changed the server.
My mysql version: 5.5.44-0+deb8u1-log - (Debian).
My my.cnf file:

- [mysqld_safe]
- pid-file  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
- socket        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
- nice      = 0
- [mysqld]
- skip-external-locking
- key_buffer_size     = 5M
- max_allowed_packet    = 16M
- thread_stack      = 192K
- thread_cache_size       = 8
- tmp_table_size = 384M
- max_heap_table_size = 384M
- table_open_cache = 7000
- open_files_limit = 14000
- interactive_timeout=3600
- wait_timeout=3600
- myisam-recover_options  = BACKUP
- max_connections        = 150
- query_cache_limit = 8M
- query_cache_size        = 127M
- slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
- slow_query_log      = 1
- long_query_time = 2
- expire_logs_days  = 10
- max_binlog_size         = 100M
- innodb_file_per_table
- innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 9
- innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10000M
- innodb_log_file_size = 2000M

It is something wrong in my configuration?

EDIT
For production we have dedicated server:

- 4 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz
- 20 GB RAM memory
- 40 GB na DHH - data base have now 15 GB
- in the data base is on this moment 650 tables on the innoDB engine

Screenshot of htop:
[htop of proces on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y95Lk.png)

Comment: Besides being somewhat off-topic, the question lacks any piece of information that can help any kind of troubleshooting. What is the memory usage, by which process, how much physical memory installed, pattern of memory usage growth etc. e.g. `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10000M` could be crazy large a value on a low end VPS, but quite reasonable for a dedicated system fitted with 16GB.

Comment: Ok you have right, I add a little information about the production server.

Comment: I think is is more appropriate for dba stackexchange.

Comment: 15GB RAM used by MySQL, where is the problem? This is consistent with your settings. 150 `max_connections` is perhaps a bit optimistic, the timeouts could be reduced a bit. You have about 20% free RAM. Your server seems to be in perfect health condition.

Comment: Ok yesterday was 14,3 GB, today morning is 15 GB.